# jquery parent().find(input).val(); accessing two input fields in one table cell on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get values on two input fields (a text field and a select field) inside a table cell with on click button.

```
<td>
    <input type="text" onkeypress="return validateNumber(event);" value="'+rate_value+'" class="thinpt" maxlength="3" />
    <select class="thinpt1" value="'+format+'">
        <option value="21">Seconds</option>
        <option value="22">Minutes</option>
        <option value="33">Hours</option>
    </select>
    <button class="setstream" type="button" data-devicevalue="'+device_value+'" data-device="'+device_id+'" data-devicetype="'+device_type+'" data-gateway="'+gateway_id+'">SET</button>
    <span class="done grn"></span>
</td>
```

In jquery am using the below script to get the input from single text field.

```
var threshold  = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
```

I don't know how to get values of two different input box using the above jquery line.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you heard of loops,multiple functions/variables??

Comment: selects don't have values

Comment: yes... but couldnt figure out using that here

Comment: i want to pass 21 or 22 or 33 to the var format based on user selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var first  = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
var second  = $(this).parent().find('select').val();
```

Comment: can you describe a little what you did here?

Comment: I just got values from the input box and select box separately using the corresponding selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Its very Easy. Try This

```
<td><input type="text" value="'+rate_value+'" class="thinpt" maxlength="3"  />
<select class="thinpt1" value"'+format+'" >
   <option value="21">Seconds</option>
   <option value="22">Minutes</option><option value="33">Hours</option>
</select>
<button class="setstream" type="button" data-devicevalue="'+device_value+'" data-device="'+device_id+'" data-devicetype="'+device_type+'" data-gateway="'+gateway_id+'">SET</button><span class="done grn"></span></td>
```

Jquery

```
$(function($){
    $(".thinpt").on('keyup',function(){
        var inputValue=$(this).parent().find('input').val();
        var selectValue=$(this).parent().find('select').val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `val()` function, create another variable to store your new value:

```js
var thinpt = $('.thinpt').val();
var thinpt1 = $('.thinpt1').val();//get the value of the selected option
var thinpt1text = $('.thinpt1 option:selected').text();//get the text of the selected option
console.log(thinpt,thinpt1,thinpt1text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validateNumber(event);" value="x" class="thinpt" maxlength="3" />
<select class="thinpt1" name="format">
<option value="21">Seconds</option>
<option value="22">Minutes</option>
<option value="33">Hours</option>
</select>
<button class="setstream" type="button" data-devicevalue="'+device_value+'" data-device="'+device_id+'" data-devicetype="'+device_type+'" data-gateway="'+gateway_id+'">SET</button><span class="done grn"></span>
```

Comment: thanks guyz... this helped me.. 
var first  = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
var second  = $(this).parent().find('select').val();